Why is my up icon is not showing in this program?
So I have little program in which up arrow icon does not show, I have checked does it load like this
void set_button_icon(GtkWidget *button, const gchar *icon_name) {
    GdkPixbuf *icon = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file(icon_name, NULL);
    if (icon == NULL) {
        g_printerr("Error loading image: %s\n", icon_name);
        return;
    }
    GtkWidget *image_widget = gtk_image_new_from_pixbuf(icon);
    gtk_button_set_image(GTK_BUTTON(button), image_widget);
}

And Im not getting an error since icon is there, I have checked for typos and could not find any, here is my code

#include <gtk/gtk.h>

GtkWidget *button_l;
GtkWidget *button_r;
GtkWidget *button_up;
gboolean left_arrow_pressed = FALSE;
gboolean right_arrow_pressed = FALSE;
gboolean up_arrow_pressed = FALSE;

void set_button_icon(GtkWidget *button, const gchar *icon_name) {
    GdkPixbuf *icon = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file(icon_name, NULL);
    if (icon == NULL) {
        g_printerr("Error loading image: %s\n", icon_name);
        return;
    }
    GtkWidget *image_widget = gtk_image_new_from_pixbuf(icon);
    gtk_button_set_image(GTK_BUTTON(button), image_widget);
}

gboolean check_key_state_l(gpointer user_data) {
    if (left_arrow_pressed) {
        g_print("Left arrow key pressed.\n");
    }
    return TRUE; // Continue the timer
}

gboolean check_key_state_r(gpointer user_data) {
    if (right_arrow_pressed) {
        g_print("Right arrow key pressed.\n");
    }
    return TRUE; // Continue the timer
}

gboolean check_key_state_up(gpointer user_data) {
    if (up_arrow_pressed) {
        g_print("Up arrow key pressed.\n");
    }
    return TRUE; // Continue the timer
}

gboolean on_key_press(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventKey *event, gpointer user_data) {
    if (event->keyval == GDK_KEY_Left) {
        if (!left_arrow_pressed) {
            left_arrow_pressed = TRUE;
            g_timeout_add(100, check_key_state_l, NULL);
        }
        set_button_icon(button_l, "pressed_icon_l.png");
        return TRUE; // Event handled
    } else if (event->keyval == GDK_KEY_Right) {
        if (!right_arrow_pressed) {
            right_arrow_pressed = TRUE;
            g_timeout_add(100, check_key_state_r, NULL);
        }
        set_button_icon(button_r, "pressed_icon_r.png");
        return TRUE; // Event handled
    } else if (event->keyval == GDK_KEY_Up) {
        if (!up_arrow_pressed) {
            up_arrow_pressed = TRUE;
            g_timeout_add(100, check_key_state_up, NULL);
        }
        set_button_icon(button_up, "pressed_icon_up.png");
        return TRUE; // Event handled
    }
    return FALSE; // Event not handled
}

gboolean on_key_release(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventKey *event, gpointer user_data) {
    if (event->keyval == GDK_KEY_Left) {
        left_arrow_pressed = FALSE;
        set_button_icon(button_l, "initial_icon_l.png");
        return TRUE; // Event handled
    } else if (event->keyval == GDK_KEY_Right) {
        right_arrow_pressed = FALSE;
        set_button_icon(button_r, "initial_icon_r.png");
        return TRUE; // Event handled
    } else if (event->keyval == GDK_KEY_Up) {
        up_arrow_pressed = FALSE;
        set_button_icon(button_up, "initial_icon_up.png");
        return TRUE; // Event handled
    }
    return FALSE; // Event not handled
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    GtkBuilder *builder;
    GtkWidget *window;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    builder = gtk_builder_new();
    gtk_builder_add_from_file(builder, "GladeUI_2.glade", NULL);
    gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder, NULL);

    window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "window1"));

    g_signal_connect(window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);


    button_l = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "button_l"));
    button_r = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "button_r"));
    button_up = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "button_up"));

    set_button_icon(button_l, "initial_icon_l.png");
    set_button_icon(button_r, "initial_icon_r.png");
    set_button_icon(button_up, "initial_icon_up.png");

    g_signal_connect(window, "key-press-event", G_CALLBACK(on_key_press), NULL);
    g_signal_connect(window, "key-release-event", G_CALLBACK(on_key_release), NULL);

    gtk_widget_show(window);
    gtk_main();

    g_object_unref(builder);

    return 0;
}

Here is how my program looks like, as you can see "up_arrow" icon is missing


Maybe the file name is incorrect. There could be many reasons. We'd have to guess, and we don't like to guess on this site. You have to provide the whole example that we could take and build and see for ourselves the problem that you see.
